# web scraping using DOM in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, dom

Below is my code wherein search variable is a string input from user. I'm checking this input against some values of tables obtained by web scraping. Even though the search value corresponds with one of the table values it does not go inside my "if statement" and print "workinggg". Can someone please help me with it I have been stuck here for days. It would be really helpful.

```
        $search =  $_POST['search_state'];
        $doc = file_get_html('https://prsindia.org/covid-19/cases');
        $table = $doc->getElementByTagName('table'); 
        $states = $table->getElementByTagName('tbody');
        for($i=0; $i<36; $i++){
            $rows = $states->getElementsByTagName('tr',$i);
            $columns = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');
            if (in_array($search, $columns)) {
                echo "workinggg";
            }
```

Comment: [getElementsByTagName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) would return a [nodelist](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) rather than a pure array so standard array methods will not work

Comment: You might find it easier to use an [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) query to find nodes of interest

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned about using an `XPath` query to simplify your problem - but without knowing the full criteria the following might or might not be wholly applicable. This example uses a `hard-coded` variable for input. I found that this particular website is very slow to load so saving a copy before running all of your XPath queries might be a better solution - certainly for the remote site  it would reduce the load a little.

```
$url='https://prsindia.org/covid-19/cases';

/*
    Save a copy locally if it does not exist to improve performance
*/
$file=sprintf('%s/%s__covid_prsindia.html', __DIR__, date('y-m-d') );
if( !file_exists( $file ) ) {
    file_put_contents( $file, file_get_contents( $url ) );
}

/*
    Display attributes for these columns
*/
$attr=array(
    'id',
    'State',
    'Cases',
    'Active',
    'Discharged',
    'Deaths'
);

/*
    This would be your POST variable
*/
$search='Assam';

/*
    Constrct your XPath expression using the previous $search variable
*/
$expr=sprintf( '//tr[@data-key]/td[2][ contains( text(), "%s" ) ]', $search );

/*
    create the DOMDocument and XPath
*/
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;

$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $file );
$errors=libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();


$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
/*
    run the query and process results
*/      
$col=$xp->query( $expr );
if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    # result targeted specific cell but we want all cells for that table row.
    $col=$col->item(0)->parentNode->childNodes;
    
    # print data found
    for( $i=1; $i < $col->length; $i++ ){
        printf( '%s: %s<br />', $attr[ $i ], $col[ $i ]->nodeValue );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this answer. I'm so glad you answered but since I'm a bit new to php could you please come on discord and explain the code to me:)